# Restricting User Access Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users) documentation, I can restrict access to applications on an Azure tenant using enterprise applications.

I tried to set this up on my B2C Tenant but when I test my user flows, I can still log in to those applications and receive an ID token.

Should the restrictions also work on the B2C Tenant or is there a different process required for B2C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using b2c User flows we can't restrict the user access. You need to handle this from the application side and also using [Custom policy you can call the REST API in the user journey](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-developer-community-blog/advanced-home-realm-discovery-in-azure-ad-b2c/ba-p/482788) and can validate user restrictions.